# What is wrong coded in my SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in my SQL query?

```
SELECT medevnaam 
FROM   medewerkers 
       ( 
                  SELECT     medewerkers.medenr, 
                             medewerkers.medevnaam 
                  FROM       medewerkers 
                  INNER JOIN roosterlijn 
                  ON         medewerkers.medenr = roosterlijn.medenr 
                  WHERE      roosternr = '1'
       ) AS test
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: A comma between the medewerkers and the opening bracket?

Answer (score 1):

You can either do

```
FROM medewerkers
INNER JOIN ...
```

or

```
FROM ( SELECT ....)
```

but not

```
from medewerkers ( select
```

try this:

```
SELECT m.medevnaam
FROM medewerkers as m
INNER JOIN roosterlijn
ON medewerkers.medenr = roosterlijn.medenr
WHERE roosternr = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether I get your question right, but shouldn't the following work?

```
SELECT medevnaam, 
        (SELECT medewerkers.medenr, 
                medewerkers.medevnaam 
           FROM medewerkers 
     INNER JOIN roosterlijn ON medewerkers.medenr = roosterlijn.medenr 
          WHERE roosternr = '1') AS test 
  FROM edewerkers
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your query should look like this

```
    SELECT medevnaam 
from 
(
   SELECT medewerkers.medenr, medewerkers.medevnaam 
   FROM medewerkers 
   INNER JOIN roosterlijn 
   on medewerkers.medenr = roosterlijn.medenr 
  WHERE roosternr = '1'
)  as test
```

hopes this helps

Answer (score 0):

Let Try the below script,

SELECT medevnaam 
FROM
       ( 
                  SELECT     medewerkers.medenr, 
                             medewerkers.medevnaam 
                  FROM       medewerkers 
                  INNER JOIN roosterlijn 
                  ON         medewerkers.medenr = roosterlijn.medenr

```
   ) AS test WHERE      roosternr = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

remove table name after from keyword

SELECT medevnaam 
from
(
   SELECT medewerkers.medenr, medewerkers.medevnaam 
   FROM medewerkers 
   INNER JOIN roosterlijn 
   on medewerkers.medenr = roosterlijn.medenr 
  WHERE roosternr = '1'
)  as test